# Azure AD B2C - Error on reset password policy custom template (error code UX016)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm using Active Directory B2C with local identity supplier with username and the directives that I'm using are: Sign-up or sign-in policies, Password reset policies both with Custom Templates.

When I try to recover the password everything works out fine until I do the verification code. When the verification code works in the e-mail and then press "continue" this is the error that's presented:

Bad Request

URL:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/prosamx.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_ResetPwd/api/SelfAsserted/error?code=UX016&desc=OK&csrf_token=Y1BjMjF2TjdMVm5MbXhyLyt4MHFzUlVsQzcyUXA2VVVZUDVoQml6S20xL2JQd3ppbHZadTBVaHl2ZTlMMUx1YkJSUkZTeVhnY2grL2lPZ3F1OE92Q1E9PTsyMDE3LTA1LTAyVDE4OjQ4OjQ2LjM5MTU4NDRaO09ZV2hNTEpoT2RYMUQwWllkLzVoSlE9PTt7IlRhcmdldEVudGl0eSI6IlBhc3N3b3JkUmVzZXRVc2luZ1VzZXJOYW1lRXhjaGFuZ2UiLCJPcmNoZXN0cmF0aW9uU3RlcCI6Mn0=&tx=eyJUSUQiOiI4MGRjODIwMC05MjA1LTRlODEtOTIyNy00NTNkMzRjNGQ3ZTUifQ&p=B2C_1_ResetPwd

This happens when used the username at the local identity provider

I hope you can help me out.

Thanks, regards.

Answer (score 1):

Password reset depends on a StrongAuthenticationEmail property on the user object and uses that to verify to do the Email address based OTP before allowing a self-service Password Reset.

If your users used the signup flow we ship out of the box to register, when the signup flow verifies the email address, b2c writes that into the StrongAuthenticationEmail property.

Based on looking at your tenant, itseems the users do not have this property set. For userName based accounts, without this property there is no other way to do **self**-service password reset. This can happen because the user's were created by a flow that directly calls AAD Graph API outside of the signup flow we offer, or you have turned off email address validation as part of the signup flow.

Thank you for reporting this issue - we will fix the error message so that it clearly states what the problem is for self-diagnosis.

Thank you,
Vikram.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting a similar unhelpful error of "Bad Request" on signup.  I verify the email address via the verification code, fill out all the fields and then bam - get the error.

https://login.microsoftonline.com//B2C_1_Login-UserName/api/SelfAsserted/error
?code=UX016
&desc=OK
&csrf_token=
&p=B2C_1_Login-UserName

Comment: This should not happen, I can help you to resolve this issue. Give me the more context here or attach your policy files(make sure remove secrets and tenat names). Attach Base, Extension, Password Reset. I can surely help you if you facing issue with local account password reset which (user) got created in the B2C directory.

Comment: I see from your policy name it refers unified signuporsignin policy. If that is the case attach signuporsignin policy file also (if you are sure there are no modifications except your tenant and base policy names then ignore)